# Fix a bad dry wall patch

Tags: patching-drywall

I patched a hole in my dry wall by putting a metal plate on it and pasting some spackling on it. As you can imagine, the wall is not flat enough to fool my landlord. How can I fix that? The hole is about 6 inches long and I used an 8 inch square plate so ripping the whole thing out is not possible.

Comment: Well you need to rip it out to fix it...

Comment: I'll have to bite the bullet on this one then. Was looking for any quick tips from experience.